# iPhone Paypal in UIWebView Appstore approval process

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, paypal

My application has paypal integration. 
I have read in many threads, they stated that paypal integration will cause the application to reject from app store. I am going to integrate paypal in uiwebview.It will be approved by App store?

My application type is just logging in and post their ads to other users. For each ads they have to pay.

Please help me out it has to be in appstore in next few days. I am reaching my deadline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it depends what you are selling in your App.

With StoreKit, you sell additional content: "*You can use this in-application payment functionality to collect payment for enhanced functionality or additional content usable by your application.*" - Apple

Therefore, if you are selling additional content using PayPal, it would be logical that Apple might have issue with this and reject your app.

If you are selling a physical item, or something that isn't additional content then I'm sure you can use PayPal. Take the eBay app for example.

I hope this helps!
N

Comment: I have one more doubt on this. If I point the url and open safari browser for payment alone. Still there is possibility of getting rejected by App Store?

Comment: I don't see why they would reject this. Although it would be a better user journey if you were to either use the PayPal API integrated directly into your project (https://developer.paypal.com/) or use a UIWebView, so the user can complete the payment without leaving your app. Good luck & please let me know how you get on. N

Comment: Would subscriptions be allowed in this case trhough PayPal, say to read news?

Comment: Any subscription to content consumed within your app would be thought of as "Additional Content". If the news is read in a reader in your app then it would fall into this category and you would not be able to use PayPal. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the method of integration - it's about Apple missing on your revenue. Their policy is - if you sell something via the app, you must provide an alternative (not necessarily exclusive) payment channel via In-App Purchases. Read up on the StoreKit framework.