# PayPal API for iOS - allowed?

Tags: iphone, paypal

Is Apple OK with the use of PayPal API in an iOS App, for selling goods and services?

Any experience? I've been reading the InApp Purchase, and it applies only to digital content.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145524/iphone-paypal-in-uiwebview-appstore-approval-process

Comment: This has been a contentious area. You should carefully read section 11 of [Apple's review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

Comment: it's not clear enough. Any experiences with approved app, except eBay app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are not selling digital goods, you can use the PayPal API. Apple does not restrict iPhone users from paying with PayPal for physical goods and real world services.

You can also use it for donations to charitable institutions.

PapPal also allows different types of payments like chained payments, parallel payments etc.

Although it does not use PayPal, you can pay for goods in the Amazon App with real money. PayPal is no different. An easily verifiable example of an app that uses paypal for sure is PayPal itself!

Comment: The in-app SDK is not permitted for charitable donations.  Doing so will get your app rejected.  This policy has been in place since some time around Q4 2010.  App Store Review Guidelines 21.2 - "The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS".

Comment: What are the "real world services" accorging to Apple rules? If we have an Internet service like Dropbox or Skype - is it "real world" or "unreal world"?

Comment: @look, my app rejected by apple for PayPal iOS SDK.i am used PayPal payment gateway for purchase image.i have done payment by Paypal.If status is success then we download image.Can you suggest any alternative way in PayPal?