# Taking credit card payments in app

Tags: android, iphone

Is there any service or api that will allow me to accept credit card payments within my iphone and android apps?

I can't find anything using an extensive google search.

Will servies like sage or similar work at all? Will I need a webview?

Thanks

Comment: Apple likely will require you to use in-app purchase instead.

Comment: Unless your selling non-digital goods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal works

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

CTRL+F "ios"

About halfway down the page.

And

[PayPal API for iOS - allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148370/paypal-api-for-ios-allowed)

Comment: Cool, I shall look into this some more. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options out there, but the cheapest and easiest solution seems to be [ZooZ](http://www.zooz.com). iOS and Android compatible, ZooZ's 3 lines of code monetizes your app in minutes. Users can pay with credit cards or PayPal.

The biggest advantages of ZooZ are that your user always stays within your app and won't have to re-enter payment details in the future, resulting in faster processing and higher conversion rates.

Of course you can always build your own credit card processing platform, but considering the challenges of security, merchant accounts, and PCI compliance, it's probably not worth the headache.

Full disclosure: I have the privilege of working at ZooZ :)

Comment: cool! does it work in the UK?

Comment: Yes it does. It has full global coverage and support multiple currencies

Comment: I think it's important to note that "cheapest and easiest solution" is somewhat subjective: ZooZ charge 2.8% plus 19c per payment. For small values this could be competitive, but if you're looking to run $3000+ per month then there are other options that could be better value.

Answer (score 2):

There is this: https://developer.mastercard.com but the payments API is not quite in production.

Comment: but I agree with ceejayoz that Apple may not let that fly

Comment: Neither will Android, if you plan on publishing to Market legally. If you publish through Market, you MUST use their in-app purchase. Unless this has changed (I did not thoroughly research for this comment, but I did a few months ago).

Comment: with apple's developer t&cs definitely (I'm not so sure about android) you're not allowed to use in app purchase to sell goods or services not specifically for use within the app (unless its changed recently)

Answer (score 0):

We have an API you can embed into your iOS app that will enable credit card swiping and processing from within your app. We expect to have the same available for Android apps late 1Q 2012. For details visit http://developers.moblized.com.

Answer (score 0):

[BrainTree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v1) seems the easiest way to integrate with Mobile app.It consists of complementary client and server SDK.

Answer (score -1):

And there's also [Square/SquareUp](https://squareup.com/).

Comment: That allows me to take physical card payments on a device, however what I'm looking for is to take it within an app.