# Will Payment via webview for iOS app (e.g. PayPal API for iOS or credit card) gets rejected by apple appstore?

Tags: ios, paypal, payment, credit-card

I've been searching StackOverflow for a while now but I still couldn't find an answer to my question.

From this link :[PayPal API for iOS - allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148370/paypal-api-for-ios-allowed)
"Yes, as long as you are not selling digital goods, you can use the PayPal API"

How do they define digital goods? Is e-Ticketing (ticket with QRcode/BarCode) considered as digital goods?

I've came across cinemas app that are approved. (Just a little paranoid here)

Comment: The point essentially is that you can use PayPal as a method of implementing in-app purchases, for products which are not digital. (Digital products e.g. e-books, in-app currency, premium version, etc). In the case of Cinema applications, a real-world service is being provided, for which the use of PayPal API is allowed.

Comment: As @akashg said, ticketing would be OK - You must use in-app purchase where the service is delivered in the app.  You cannot use in-app purchase where the service is not delivered in the app.  So, ticket for a movie at a cinema - You cannot use in-app purchase.  Movie to be viewed in the app - you must use in-app purchase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app purchases and payments in a WebView are two different things. There's no rule that states that you can not initiate payments in a WebView inside the app. That's completely acceptable. For In App purchases, you must follow Apple's guidelines which state that the content sold within the app must use Apple's in-app purchase. For other physical commodities/goods, you can use Paypal's iOS SDK.