# HOLLER: Secure Payment over API & Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium studio to build an iphone mobile app, and I want to do the following

- Send a user id using API to my server
- Server processes payment for that user using the previous card on file
- Server sends a success/failure response.

What is the most secure way to do this? I know if I just send the user id then anyone could hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure what your doing is allowed (roll-your-own Payments and credit cards in-app will generally get you rejected)

Make sure your app does not violate any of these guidelines:

> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>   rejected
>
> 11.13  Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes
>   to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Check the latest App store review guidelines here : https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Also refer to these SO questions for more information:
[iPhone Paypal in UIWebView Appstore approval process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145524/iphone-paypal-in-uiwebview-appstore-approval-process)
[iOS - Integrating credit card payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762096/ios-integrating-credit-card-payments)

A more secure way to do this (if you pass all the above guidelines) would be to use a userid, **password**, and **salt**, encrypted either over `https` or `SHA256`. Note that you have to specify you use encryption if you go the second route, during the review process.

[Here is a wikipedia article about Salt and Passwords that I used.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

[Here is a SHA256 library for JavaSCript that works great with Titanium and is simple to use.](http://point-at-infinity.org/jssha256/)